# how to find out in datagridview repeat the same value

Tags: c#

i have one  datagridview.in my datagridview is having four row and three columns.after enter the one row. that row one coloumns value repeat (or) same in second row columns value.so,how to find out the which value is repeat and which row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your grid data is mainly text then maintain a `List<string>` that holds all of the values being inserted in the **DataGridView**.

So every time data was entered in a cell (there are events you can handle for that, like `CellEndEdit` or `CellLeave`), you check if it is in your list of strings before you add it.

If it is, then you found a value already contained within the grid.

**EDIT**
Here is some sample code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   string cellVal = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
   if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(listGridVals.Find(delegate(string s) { return s == cellVal; })))
       listGridVals.Add(cellVal);
   else
       MessageBox.Show("Value: " + cellVal + " already in the grid!");

}
```

**NOTE**

This routine is very basic, it only checks if values being entered in the grid are 
already in the `List<string>`.

However, let's say that you already have value *test* in one cell and already in the `List<string>`.

What happens when you delete that value and enter a *test1* ? Well, *test* will still be in `List<string>` and next time you enter *test* in another cell you'll get the `MessageBox` saying there is already a *test* in the grid, which could be wrong.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you only input text in your grid? (ie there are no comboboxes editors for selecting values from a list, or checkboxes to check, etc)